# Unexpected results using pandas .loc - trying to concatenate 2 columns based on a condition

Tags: pandas, concatenation, pandas-loc

I have a df where I am trying to merge 2 columns based on a condition.

Create df

```
df = em_df[['Redcap_Case_num', 'EV_EM',  'COMP_EM', 'EV_RND', 'COMP_EM_RND'] ].head(3)
df.to_clipboard(excel = False, sep = ', ')

#Add EMFREAS - RND columns to df
cols_to_fill=[x for x in ln.columns if x.startswith("EMFREAS")]

for column in cols_to_fill:
    df[column] = ln[column].copy()
df.to_clipboard(excel = False, sep = ', ')
```

Output - Please understand I have tried to follow the instructions to format the table, but the instructions did not work for me.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong so this is how I was able to do it.

```
ID        EV_EM     COMP_EM          EV_RND      COMP_EM_RND     EMFREAS1   EMFREAS2 
YA007      1        Not Done                   Insufficient                                                                                
YA006      1                                                                                                                                              
YA005      0        Outside grid  EM Not done
```

I need to merge the EV_RND column and the COMP_EM_RND columns to populate all the columns that start with EMFREAS (You are only seeing a subset of the columns)

Here is the code I am trying to use to do this:

```
#apply ND filter to df and merge to ln df

EV_ND = df["EV_EM"]==0 
EM_ND = df['COMP_EM'] == 'Not Done'

df.loc[EV_ND | EM_ND, cols_to_fill]=df["EV_RND"] + '|' + df["COMP_EM_RND"]
```

The expected outcome should look like this:

```
ID       EV_EM COMP_EM          EV_RND      COMP_EM_RND     EMFREAS1            EMFREAS2 
YA007    1        Not Done      EV ND        Insufficient   Insufficient|EV ND Insufficient|EV ND                                                                          
YA006    1                                                                                                                                              
YA005    1        Outside grid  EM Not done                EM Not done           EM Not done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the empty values in your df are actually empty strings, you can create a separator series equal to `|` if `EV_RND` and `COMP_EM_RND` are not empty, empty string otherwise. Then concat `EV_RND`, the separator series and `COMP_EM_RND`:

```
sep_series = df.apply(lambda x: '|'
                        if (x['EV_RND'] and x['COMP_EM_RND'])
                        else '', axis=1)

fill_series = df['EV_RND'].str.cat(sep_series).str.cat(df['COMP_EM_RND'])

for col in df.columns:
    if col.startswith('EMFREAS'):
        df[col] = df[col].replace('', np.nan).fillna(fill_series)
```

Output:

```
      ID  EV_EM       COMP_EM       EV_RND   COMP_EM_RND            EMFREAS1            EMFREAS2
0  YA007      1      Not Done        EV ND  Insufficient  EV ND|Insufficient  EV ND|Insufficient
1  YA006      1                                                                                 
2  YA005      0  Outside grid  EM Not done                       EM Not done         EM Not done
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked, but it applied an empty string to all fields, which is not what I need.  I have other data in these columns that can't be overwritten which is why I need to base it on a condition.

Comment: Oh now it makes more sense! In that case you'll want to use fillna. I edited my answer!

Comment: This doesn't work.  This won't populate the data correctly, because it's not an AND condition.  It's an OR plus  I don't need it to overwrite data with an empty string.  I need it to  add (concatenate) all data in EV_RND or COMP_EM_RND  in the EMFREAS columns. ( Only if the condition is met).  I don't want it to overwrite data.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Changed to an OR and it worked perfect!  Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you... the AND condition only affects the separator `|` (no need for separator if one of the values is an empty string). In my code I replace empty string with `np.nan` in order to apply `fillna`... Glad it's working though!

Comment: Based on the way our data is setup, the above is not going to work.   (even thought the code works perfectly; its our data that is the issue.  Is there anyway I can make this work.  Does anyone see a problem with this?   <code> cols_to_fill=[x for x in ln.columns if x.startswith("LMFREAS")]
for col in df.columns:
    if col.startswith('LMFREAS'):
        df[col].apply(df['COMP_LM_RND'], df[col])
df <code>

Comment: Does `df[col] = df[col].str.cat(fill_series, sep='|')` instead of `df[col] = df[col]......fillna(fill_series)` do what you're looking for?